# SpriteKit Bool Errors

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, sprite-kit, frame-rate

I am having an error with my code, I am having an issue with my code, So I have a settings bundle that defines whether SpriteKit shows the Nodes and FPS in the scene and this code works, it just when I run it in the simulator it gets an problem at the last line and says it has a problem with the view controller running `theScene` and doesnt load my scene but when I am in the simulator I can click on the app and it runs all fine, I have no idea what the problem is?

And also, is there a way to reset whether the `skView` shows the FPS count, when I go back into the app from the homescreen (while the app is running)?

```
- (void)startScene
{
    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if(!skView.scene)
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        BOOL statsForNerds = [defaults boolForKey:@"myKeyName"];
        if (statsForNerds)
        {
            skView.showsFPS = YES;
            skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            skView.showsFPS = NO;
            skView.showsNodeCount = NO;
        }
        MyScene *theScene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        theScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:theScene];
    }
} //Here's the problem line (According to Xcode)
```

Comment: okay, but what's the error message? what is xcode complaining about?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Here's the error http://i.imgur.com/vHSJCiN.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqIkk.png) is not an error, Xcode hit a breakpoint that you set.

A breakpoint stops execution of the running program before the highlighted line is executed, allowing you to see the values of variables and step through code to debug. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html